# Статус код 0 при получении response с сервера

Tags: javascript, java, servlet

Имеется страничка с формой и парой кнопок

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Site</title>
    <script>
        function signInAction(){
            console.log("Sign In");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/auth', true);
            xhr.send();

            var log = document.getElementById('login').value;
            var pas = document.getElementById('password').value;

            console.log("LOGIN: " + log + " PASSWORD " + pas);

            var body = 'login=' + encodeURIComponent(log) +
                       '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pas);

            xhr.open("POST", '/auth', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');   
            xhr.send(body);
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
            } else {
                console.log( xhr.responseText ); 
            }
        }
        function signUpAction(){
            console.log("Sign Up");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Login Please</p>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Login: <input id="login" type="text" name="login"/>
    Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"/>

</form>
<button name="SignIn" onclick="signInAction()">Sign In</button>
<button name="SignUp" onclick="signUpAction()">Sign Up </button>
</body>
</html>
```

и имеется сервлет который должен обработать запрос при нажатии на кнопку `Sign In`

```
public class SingInServlet extends HttpServlet {

    AccountService accountService;

    public SingInServlet(AccountService accountService){
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doPost: login: " + req.getParameter("login") + " password " + req.getParameter("password"));

        resp.getWriter().println("SIGNING IN");

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doDelete(req, resp);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getRequestParametres(HttpServletRequest req){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("pathInfo", req.getPathInfo());
        map.put("context", req.getContextPath());
        map.put("method", req.getMethod());
        map.put("session", req.getSession().getId());
        map.put("URL", req.getRequestURI().toString());

        return map;
    }
}
```

класс Main:

```
public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // write your code here
        AccountService accountService = new AccountService();

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SingUpServlet(accountService)), "/reg");
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SingInServlet(accountService)), "/auth");  
        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setResourceBase("public_page");
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resource_handler, context});
        server.setHandler(handlers);    
        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Server started");
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

При вводе данных в поля и нажатии на кнопку `Sign In` запрос идет на сервер, но вот ответ обратно на клиент не приходит, в итоге выскакиевает алерт с текстом `0:`.

Почему так произошло и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете асинхронный запрос и не дожидаетесь получения ответа, а сразу выводите статус. Вам нужно добавить обработчик (`xhr.onreadystatechange = function ...`), который будет вызван при получении ответа от сервера. См., например, [руководство от Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/AJAX/%D0%A1_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.A8.D0.B0.D0.B3_2.C2.A0.E2.80.94_.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.B5.D0.BC_.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.82_.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0). Или используйте так популярные сейчас библиотеки, типа jQuery.

Также вы почему-то два раза отправляете запрос на сервер, эта часть мне непонятна.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. По поводу двойного запроса - видимо лишний поставил, надо убрать